# Request Inicial con React Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

Estoy realizando una consulta a la Pokeapi con React a través de axios. La solicitud se realiza pero, no puedo mostrar los datos en pantalla porque mi propiedad pokemons[] está vacía, es decir primero se hace la solicitud y luego se monta el componente y ahí es dónde la propiedad sigue vacía.

He intentado realizarlo a través de hooks, con useState y luego setear la propiedad pokemones en el useEffect, y en el mismo useEffect es dónde realizo la petición a la api, la muestro por pantalla y si llega con datos.

Aquí está mi App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import { Button, Accordion, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

import "./style.css";

import HolaComponent from "./HolaComponent";
import AdiosComponent from "./AdiosComponent";

import Saludar from "./SaludarComponent";

import Contacto from "./pages/Contacto";
import About from "./pages/About";
import ListPokemon from "./pages/ListPokemon";

export default function App() {
  let pokes = [];

  const [pokemons, setPokemones] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    pokemonsListado().then(data => {
      setPokemones(JSON.stringify(data.results));
      console.log(`data ${JSON.stringify(data.results)}`);
    });
    console.log(pokemons);
  }, []);

  let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10`;

  // const pokemonsListado = async () => {
  async function pokemonsListado() {
    await axios.get(url).then(res => {
      pokes = JSON.stringify(res.data.results);
      console.log(`response: ${JSON.stringify(res.data.results)}`);
      // return JSON.stringify(res.data.results);
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Link to="/">
          <Button>Home</Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/about">
          <Button>About</Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/contacto">
          <Button>Contacto</Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/pokemons">
          <Button>Pokemons</Button>
        </Link>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contacto">
            <Contacto />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/pokemons">
            <ListPokemon />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>

      <Saludar />
    </>
  );
}
```

Y aquí mi componente de Pokemones:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

export default function ListPokemon() {
  let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10`;
  // let pokemons = props.pokemons;
  const [pokemons, setPokemones] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    pokemonsListado().then(data => {
      setPokemones(JSON.stringify(data.results));
      console.log(`data ${JSON.stringify(data.results)}`);
    });
    console.log(pokemons);
  }, []);

  // const pokemonsListado = async () => {
  async function pokemonsListado() {
    await axios.get(url).then(res => {
      pokes = JSON.stringify(res.data.results);
      console.log(`response: ${JSON.stringify(res.data.results)}`);
      // return JSON.stringify(res.data.results);
    });
  }

  console.log("los " + pokemons);
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {pokemons.map(p => (
          <li>{p.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Lo que quiero realizar es algo así como en **Angular** que tiene su **OnInit** y puedes inicializar datos al momento que se carga el componente.

Estoy trabajando este ejemplo en la plataforma StackBlitz, para que se entienda mejor el problema, dejo el enlace del recurso:

[React y pokeapi](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-learning-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Vamos por partes:

El ciclo de vida `OnInit` en `Angular`, puede tener su contraparte en `React` en un metodo llamado `componentDidMount`, el cual solo se ejecutará una vez y lo puedes simular con `hooks` tal como lo tienes actualmente:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // TODO:
}, []);
```

Ahora tratemos de entender que estás realizando prácticamente lo mismo tanto en el componente `App` como en `ListPokemon` (lo cual está mal) y ya esto depende de a quien quieras delegarle la responsabilidad de realizar la petición, obtener la información y ponerla en el estado.

> Yo voy a delegarle esta responsabilidad al componente `App` y le voy a pasar la lista de pokemones como un prop al componente `ListPokemon`

Con lo de arriba aclarado procedo a ayudarte a mejorar tu componente `App` de la siguiente manera, (lo voy a simplificar y eliminar código innecesario para que sea claro):

```
export default function App() {
  const [pokemons, setPokemones] = useState([]);
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10`;

  // Convertimos tu función a un arrow function para evitar posibles errores de scope
  const pokemonsListado = async () => {
    // Si ya estamos utilizando utilidades asíncronas no hay necesidad
    // de implementar esta función como una promesa, la cual podemos
    // simplificar mucho mejor de la siguiente manera:

    // Realizamos nuestra petición
    const req = await axios.get(url);
    // Los pokemones obtenidos de dicha petición
    const pokemones = await req.data.results;
    // Hacemos uso de nuestro hook y ponemos en el estado
    // a nuestros pokemones
    setPokemones(pokemones);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Ejecutamos nuestra función una vez el componente se monte
    pokemonsListado();
  }, []);

  // Pasamos nuestro valor del estado como un prop a nuestro componente hijo
  return <ListPokemon pokemons={pokemons} />;
}
```

Y no siendo más, nuestro componente hijo se podría simplificar para evitar la redundancia de peticiones y manejo de información de la siguiente manera:

```
export default function ListPokemon({ pokemons }) {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {pokemons.map(p => (
          <li>{p.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Aquí como último recurso te dejo un ejemplo totalmente aislado de lo que quieres hacer basado en tu snippet, funcional e implementado como lo acabo de describir en toda esta respuesta: [React-Axios-PokeAPI](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-learning-react-9epukn)